# Ambari - Execute script when adding node to cluster

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Is it possible (and how) to specify a shell script somewhere which will be executed each time a new node is added to Ambari cluster?

I'm using HDP Ambari for that and I would like to add some symbolic links when setup of new node is completed, but I want to automatize that so that I (or someone else) don't forget it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality that currently exists that will enable you to execute a script when a node is added to the cluster. What you're asking for is a custom hook. You would have to look through the Ambari source code and see if you can define a custom hook for the stack. There are a few hooks provided in each stack, for examples see: https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks